# Where does the 'data' table come from in this Azure Graph Kusto?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

From the Azure Portal Virtual Machines blade I can click on the "Open Query" button and it will open a Kusto Graph query in Azure Graph Explorer. I have dissected most of the query and I believe I understand most of it. One thing I can't figure out is where the 'data' table comes from in this join:

```
| join kind=leftouter hint.strategy=shuffle (data 
    | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces' 
    | extend ipConfigsCount=array_length(properties.ipConfigurations) 
    | mvexpand ipconfig=properties.ipConfigurations limit 400
    | where ipConfigsCount == 1 or ipconfig.properties.primary =~ 'true'
```

It does it again later in a different join. Is this some Kusto placeholder table? What is the significance of 'data'?

Answer (score 1):

There are no Kusto placeholder tables, so this must be a real table or function in the database named `data`.